# How to append the logs in python

Tags: python-2.7

There are two files named file1 and file2 in the python project.

In file1.py , Iam capturing the log to file 'sample.log' and executing the file2.py through os.system() command.
In file2.py, I am opening the sample log file sample.log in appending mode and sending logs to that file.

I have executed the file1.py, even though I have opened the log file(file2.py) in append mode , I am unable to see the file2.py log.
File2 contents are overridden by file1 contents.

How Can I append file2.py logs with file1.py logs in sample.log?

**file1.py**

```
import logging
import os

logFile = 'sample.log'
logging.basicConfig( filename = logFile,filemode = 'w',level = logging.DEBUG,format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',\
                     datefmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' )

logging.debug("Starting of the file1")

os.system("python file2.py")

for i in range(0,2):
    logging.debug("Iam in file1")
```

**file2.py:**

```
import logging

logFile = 'sample.log'
logging.basicConfig( filename = logFile,filemode = 'a',level = logging.DEBUG,format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s',\
                     datefmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' )

for i in range(0,2):
   logging.debug("Iam in file2")
```

Need the output like this

> 03/06/2015 08:02:03 PM - DEBUG: Starting of the file1
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:03 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file2
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:03 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file2
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:03 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file1
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:03 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file1

but getting like this:

> 03/06/2015 08:02:49 PM - DEBUG: Starting of the file1
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:49 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file1
>
> 03/06/2015 08:02:49 PM - DEBUG: Iam in file1

Could someone help in this to get my expected output, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11):

You are getting only logs from `file1` (and sometimes few lines from `file2` at the end of the logfile) because whenever file2 writes something to the log it (roughly) first seeks to the end of the file and then writes the data (`filemode='a'`) but when `file1` writes to the file it only writes the data and its position in the file is not updated and it overwrites any lines from `file2` (`filemode='w'`).

What you want is use `filemode='a'` in **both** files.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main faults with your approach:

1. There should only be one logger on a file. If you are going to use `os.system` you'll have to use two log files because you can't open a duplicate Logger handle in file2.py.
2. You have different write-modes which causes a race condition. It could be that your `filemode='a'` completes all of its writes and then `filemode='w'` overwrites the log file from the start, clearing all previously written "file2" logging output.

Comment: 1.Isnt possible to capture both file ( file1.py and file2.py) logs into same log.

Comment: It is, see my answer. But @msw is right that it will not be guaranteed to be safe (unless the underlying system can provide such guarantees, because i don't think python would take care of that), although for simple use cases it is possible to easily achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Both

```
handler=logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w')
```

and

```
handler=logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w+')
```

always append in Python 2.7, on both Windows and Linux.

This is a bug, but I doubt they will fix it in 2.7, since it will be EOL in 2020.

Comment: Its still overwriting the file. Should I add anything else other than the above command in order to append the same log file in Python 3.6?